# insertBefore: The child to insert before is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, html

I am rewriting a jquery dragable script to plain javascript. At the `insertBefore` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) point I get this error message:
`NotFoundError: Node.insertBefore: Child to insert before is not a child of this node.`

This error occurs when I want to move a lower list element to the top.

Here is my code.

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll("#items-list > li");

items.forEach((item) => {
  item.setAttribute("draggable", true);
  item.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
  item.addEventListener("drop", dropped);
  item.addEventListener("dragenter", cancelDefault);
  item.addEventListener("dragover", cancelDefault);
});

const getNodeIndex = elm => [...elm.parentNode.children].indexOf(elm)

function dragStart(e) {
  const index = getNodeIndex(e.target);  
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", index);
}

function dropped(e) {
  cancelDefault(e);

  // get new and old index
  let oldIndex = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  let target = e.target;
  let newIndex = getNodeIndex(e.target);

  let droppedElement = e.currentTarget.parentNode.children[oldIndex];
  droppedElement.remove();
  
  // insert the dropped items at new place
  if (newIndex < oldIndex) {
    //---> this is the problematic line <---
    target.insertBefore(droppedElement, e.currentTarget.parentNode);
  } else {
    target.after(droppedElement);
  }
}

function cancelDefault(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="items-list" class="moveable">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
      <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you adding the UL element? `e.currentTarget.parentNode`

Comment: @epascarello That's a good question. I seriously did not know what the second parameter should be. So I thought I would pass the parent element as the second. In the original jquery version the function before() is used. https://codepen.io/PJCHENder/pen/PKBVRO/?editors=1010

Comment: Documentation FTW! :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

Comment: You are saying childNode, append this node after the UL....

Comment: UL is the element. `console.log(e.currentTarget.parentNode)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying to append the li after the UL. The correct way would be

`e.currentTarget.parentNode.insertBefore(droppedElement, target);`

But you are using the old way, just use before.

```
target.before(droppedElement);
```

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll("#items-list > li");

items.forEach((item) => {
  item.setAttribute("draggable", true);
  item.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
  item.addEventListener("drop", dropped);
  item.addEventListener("dragenter", cancelDefault);
  item.addEventListener("dragover", cancelDefault);
});

const getNodeIndex = elm => [...elm.parentNode.children].indexOf(elm)

function dragStart(e) {
  const index = getNodeIndex(e.target);  
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", index);
}

function dropped(e) {
  cancelDefault(e);

  // get new and old index
  let oldIndex = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  let target = e.target;
  let newIndex = getNodeIndex(e.target);

  let droppedElement = e.currentTarget.parentNode.children[oldIndex];
  droppedElement.remove();
  
  console.log(droppedElement, e.currentTarget.parentNode);
  
  // insert the dropped items at new place
  if (newIndex < oldIndex) {
    //---> this is the problematic line <---
    target.before(droppedElement);
  } else {
    target.after(droppedElement);
  }
}

function cancelDefault(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="items-list" class="moveable">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
      <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the dragged node into the `target.parentNode`, and before the `target`:

> The insertBefore() method of the Node interface inserts a node before a reference node as a child of a specified parent node.

```
target.parentNode.insertBefore(droppedElement, target);
```

**Example**:

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll("#items-list > li");

items.forEach((item) => {
  item.setAttribute("draggable", true);
  item.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
  item.addEventListener("drop", dropped);
  item.addEventListener("dragenter", cancelDefault);
  item.addEventListener("dragover", cancelDefault);
});

const getNodeIndex = elm => [...elm.parentNode.children].indexOf(elm)

function dragStart(e) {
  const index = getNodeIndex(e.target);
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", index);
}

function dropped(e) {
  cancelDefault(e);

  // get new and old index
  let oldIndex = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  let target = e.target;
  let newIndex = getNodeIndex(e.target);

  let droppedElement = e.currentTarget.parentNode.children[oldIndex];
  
  // insert the dropped items at new place
  if (newIndex < oldIndex) {
    //---> this is the problematic line <---
    target.parentNode.insertBefore(droppedElement, target);
  } else {
    target.after(droppedElement);
  }
}

function cancelDefault(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="items-list" class="moveable">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
      <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Another option is to use `Element.before()` in the same way you use `Element.after()`:

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll("#items-list > li");

items.forEach((item) => {
  item.setAttribute("draggable", true);
  item.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
  item.addEventListener("drop", dropped);
  item.addEventListener("dragenter", cancelDefault);
  item.addEventListener("dragover", cancelDefault);
});

const getNodeIndex = elm => [...elm.parentNode.children].indexOf(elm)

function dragStart(e) {
  const index = getNodeIndex(e.target);
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", index);
}

function dropped(e) {
  cancelDefault(e);

  // get new and old index
  let oldIndex = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  let target = e.target;
  let newIndex = getNodeIndex(e.target);

  let droppedElement = e.currentTarget.parentNode.children[oldIndex];
  
  // insert the dropped items at new place
  if (newIndex < oldIndex) {
    target.before(droppedElement); // <- before
  } else {
    target.after(droppedElement);
  }
}

function cancelDefault(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="items-list" class="moveable">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
      <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```